# What is wrong with my redux dispatch statement?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am getting data from local storage and wanna dispatch a redux function.
But I think the action is not calling the `try block` in the function.

**In the redux**

```
export function testLogin(loginStatus) {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
    alert('me here')
      dispatch({
        type: TEST_LOGIN_STATUS,
        payload: loginStatus,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('not logged in');
    }
  };
}

export const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGGED_IN:
      return {...state, token: action.payload, loggedIn: true};
    case TEST_LOGIN_STATUS:
      return {...state, loggedIn: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

as you can see I am getting the status as param for `testLogin` action function.

Here is what I am doing in the Home screen.When user open the app. I need to test if the user is logged in or not by checking the `local storage`

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function getStorageValue() {
            let value;
            try {
                value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
                if (value === 'true') {
                    dispatch(testLogin(true));
                } else {
                    dispatch(testLogin(false));
                }
            } catch (e) {
                // handle here
            } finally {
            }
        }
        getStorageValue();
    }, []);
```

Since `Async storage` accept only `strings` in am testing the value and returning true or false.

The thing is even if I am logged in. The when I check the redux `loginStatus` I am always `logged out` . Is there anything wrong with dispatch function?

Comment: How *do* you check the `loginStatus`? Are your actions visible in the devtools? Do you see any state change there? What do you get logging `value`?

Also, pelase note that generally you are using a very outdated style of Redux here and might have been following an outdated tutorial. Modern Redux does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPE constants, immutable reducer logic or connect.
I'd highly recommend going through [the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `testLogin` is a higher order function. i.e. it returns a function that accepts dispatch as an argument.

In your `useEffect` `try` block try the following:

```js
testLogin(value === 'true')(dispatch)
```

(replacing the if/else)

Comment: No, that is fine. That is a `thunk` action and as long as the `redux-thunk` middleware is loaded, this will work. If it isn't, it would give them an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong. But are you targeting the testLogin correctly?

For example I've seen this issue before and people simply forgot to target the Action correctly.

For example an object named LoginActions.

```
const LoginActions = {... testLogin(loginStatus) { ...} }
```

And then in the Code where I want to dispatch

```
import { LoginActions } from "../store/LoginActions" //<-- Import here

useEffect(() => {
    async function getStorageValue() {
        let value;
        try {
            value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
            if (value === 'true') {
                dispatch(LoginActions.testLogin(true)) //<-- Dispatch here.
            } else {
                dispatch(LoginActions.testLogin(false));
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // handle here
        } finally {
        }
    }
    getStorageValue();
}, []);
```

Again, I might have misunderstood but I was just wondering if this was the case?